# How can I get three function for one field in different states

Tags: sql

I have a `product` table and I want to get sum of qty is different states

Here is my table ...

```
kind|  qty  
1   |  150
8   |  122
1   |  177
3   |  60
8   |  66
...
```

How can I get this statement

```
select sum(qty) when kind=1, sum(qty) when kind=8, sum(qty) when kind=3, 
sum1+sum2-sum3 from mytable
```

The last row I want to get calc field from this statement in my sql

```
sum1+sum2-sum3 from mytable
```

and the result will be

```
sum1 , sum2, sum3, calc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
SELECT 
sum(CASE kind WHEN 1 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) kind1, 
sum(CASE kind WHEN 0 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) kind8, 
sum(CASE kind WHEN 3 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) kind3, 
sum(CASE kind WHEN 1 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) 
+ sum(CASE kind WHEN 0 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) 
+ sum(CASE kind WHEN 3 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) Total, 
FROM 
    mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  kind1, kind8, kind3, (kind1 + kind8 - kind3) totalResult
FROM
(
    SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN kind = 1 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) kind1,
            SUM(CASE WHEN kind = 8 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) kind8,
            SUM(CASE WHEN kind = 3 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) kind3
    FROM tableName
) x
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41dbc/1)

Comment: +1 : This structure is much more maintainable than pre-optimising the calculation for "totalResult". *(And potentially very slightly quicker as it recycles the three aggregates rather than creating a fourth aggregate.   Although, I would put a `WHERE` clause in the sub-query to restrict the aggregation to only kinds `1,3,8`)*

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    sum(case when kind in (1) then qty else 0 end) as sum1,
    sum(case when kind in (8) then qty else 0 end) as sum2,
    sum(case when kind in (3) then qty else 0 end) as sum3,
    sum(case when kind in (1, 8) then qty else -qty end) as calc
from mytable
where kind in (1, 3, 8)
```

Comment: well, some minor issues there, but overall it's working
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dc76/1